How to copy line number of lstlistings into a counter?
The last line of an lstlisting is stored in \lst@lineno --- while it can be accessed using:
\newcounter{gcpyn}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{gcpyn}{\lst@lineno}
\makeatother

trying to wrap that up in a macro fails:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcounter{gcpyn}
\lstset{numbers=left}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
1
2
3
\end{lstlisting}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{gcpyn}{\lst@lineno}
\makeatother

\lstset{firstnumber=\thegcpyn}
\begin{lstlisting}
4
5
6
\end{lstlisting}

\newcommand{\updatelineno}[1]{\makeatletter
\setcounter{#1}{\lst@lineno}
\makeatother
}

\updatelineno{gcpyn}

\lstset{firstnumber=\thegcpyn}
\begin{lstlisting}
7
8
9
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

with the error message:

What is the trick/technique to allow lst@lineno to be parsed so that it will provide the last line number of the previous lstlisting environment?
EDIT: to aid in searching/finding, here is a partial transcription of the error message from a similar file:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \global \csname c@abc\endcsname \lst 
                                     @lineno\relax 
l.26 \updatelineno{abc}


change \lstset{firstnumber=\thegcpyn} to lstset{firstnumber = last}

Thanks! That only works when I correct my error which @egreg had pointed out, having the make... commands inside the definition. I'm managing three different files and trying to keep the line numbers consistent w/ the files which are being written out.

Usual problem: \makeatletter and \makeatother should go outside the definition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{gcpyn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\updatelineno}[1]{\setcounter{#1}{\lst@lineno}}
\makeatother

\lstset{numbers=left,numberstyle=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
1
2
3
\end{lstlisting}

\updatelineno{gcpyn}

\lstset{firstnumber=\thegcpyn}
\begin{lstlisting}
4
5
6
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

However, listings already has the feature:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberstyle=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
1
2
3
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{firstnumber=last}
\begin{lstlisting}
4
5
6
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


However, if you need to remember the last line number to be used for a later listings, you can do as follows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberstyle=\scriptsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rememberlastline}[1]{%
  \ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand{#1}{\the\lst@lineno}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
1
2
3
\end{lstlisting}

\rememberlastline{\foo}

\begin{lstlisting}
This listing
starts from 1
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{firstnumber=\foo}
\begin{lstlisting}
4 this one
5 restarts
6 from 4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Thanks. I should defer on posting here late at night until I've slept on things...
